# Ошибка Unable to cast COM object

Tags: c#, .net

Использую .NET Framework 4.7.2 и пакет Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

При выполнении следующего кода `Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();` возникает ошибка:

```
System.InvalidCastException Сообщение = Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to 
interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation failed because the 
QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Библиотека не зарегистрирована. (0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interop требует предустановки самого поставщика т.е. MS Excel. Если excel установлен то посмотрите по этой ссылке [тут](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ru/c%23/nevozmozhno-preobrazovat-com-obekt-tipa-microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass-v-microsoft.office.interop.excel.application/1051788943/amp/)

Comment: Не стал морочиться и использую  EPPlus. Он работает корректно.